# nav bar is not displaying but working correctly in flutter flow App

Tags: firebase, flutterflow

I created a simple App on flutter flow in which i am trying to display nav bar but the icons of nav bar are not displayed but these are working correctly. In preview mode nav bar is displaying
[image]
In test Mode the nav bar is not displayed
[image]

Please if any one can help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this page is the homepage (first page) of your app, I may have an answer. Flutterflow support tells me that the navbar will not show on the homepage unless/until the user is authenticated.

I haven't found this in their docs anywhere and am still trying to find workarounds, but figured I'd post just in case it's helpful to you. The only options they suggested are 1) make user sign in first (makes no sense for my app) or 2) build a custom nav.

UPDAT: Option 3, and the one I went with: create a dummy screen that is the opening screen of the app that immediately redirects the user to the real home screen. The real home screen will then behave normally and show the nav. Dumb, but it works, and is much easier than building your own nav.

Comment: Homepage is not first page of my app. After users login then redirect to homepage